# Firing modal function onload

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I am using Ng2-modal, and cannot figure out how to fire the myModal.open() function as soon as the page loads. If you attach it to a button `(click)="myModal.open"` everything works fine. After a lot of research I have seen answers referencing spys, hooks, and complex Jquery functions. Is there no simple way to just call a function similar to javascripts `onload="myModal.open()"`?

Answer (score 0):

@Viewchild and ngOnInit() solved this for me, here is an example as followed.

**component**

```
@Component({
    template: ' <modal #mymodal>
        <modal-header>
            <h1>test</h1>
        </modal-header>

        <modal-content>
           test test test
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>',      
   })
     export class GasTroubleComponent implements OnInit {
       @ViewChild('mymodal') mymodal: Modal;

       ngOnInit(){
       this.modalSoundVerification.open();
    }
```